My js script uses 'require', which I can't use in browser. Will changing to 'import' fix this and when should I avoid 'require' altogether?
I am setting up a webhook receiver just to learn the ropes. I have run a number of tests that work fine with node. Now I am attempting to put this receiver on a publicly hosted page so that I don't have to keep my personal computer on at all times. But when I open the file in browser I get the error Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined. If I just change the "require" lines to "import" will that fix the problem?
Separately, if 'require' can't be used in browser, when is it appropriate and when should I just avoid using it from the start?
I have tried esbuild but that gave me a whole new set of errors and I am wondering if there is a more efficient solution before I go further down that path?


If I just change the "require" lines to "import" will that fix the problem?

There's other subtle differences, but I would say try it!

Separately, if 'require' can't be used in browser, when is it appropriate and when should I just avoid using it from the start?

New code should not use require(). It's serverside/node only and import / ESM is the future.

I have tried esbuild but that gave me a whole new set of errors and I am wondering if there is a more efficient solution before I go further down that path?

esbuild, webpack, vite, and others are tools that parse your Node.js style code and turn it into a single browser-compatible file. So yes this is an option if you don't want to change your code. If you want to avoid bundlers then ESM is probably the only option
